# MiniPC started showing black screen overnight

Tags: bios, fedora, power

The device in question is Minisforum HM80. I swapped SSD to larger one (with no heatsink, maybe it matters here), installed Fedora and it was running great for a couple of months (though I started to hear some coil whine noise over the last days), when suddenly one morning when I've tried to wake it up from sleep the screen stayed black. The power was on and the fans were working but nothing on the screen. Tried to turn it off, even a minute press didn't help, so I needed to cut it off from the power. Changed video cable and turned it on again - the same. Disconnected everything and tried with only monitor and power - same. Both times powering off by pulling the cord. Browsed a bit for similar issues, and found that disconnecting and reconnecting RAM could help. Did that, all the same again. Last thing I've tried is pressing reset hole for 30 sec - and still everything the same. Also, now it turns on the moment you plug it into wall power, not when pressing the power button.

Update: The monitor is good (with other PC), I've tried disconnecting CMOS battery for 15 minutes, still the same... As soon as you plug it into power outlet, it starts without pressing the power button, you can hear the fans, but nothing on display. I also tried swapping/removing one RAM sticks, didn't help. It's possible that one night power went off and it was set in BIOS to start when the power comes back (something I saw later that it's an option in BIOS, I think default), but something messed it up.

Anyone have any ideas what is happening here, or any ideas how could I get to BIOS (yes, I've tried pressing DEL/F7 on start few times)? Thanks

UPDATE #2: After speaking with a tech rep, he thinks it's a hardware issue. I still hope there still may be a fix for this, I've never had such issues, that 0 ports are working. HDMI/DP, USB 2.0/USB 3.0, monitor goes into power saving mode and I can't switch caps lock/num lock lights. The CPU fan is working, there is no PSU (adapter).

Should I try buying a new stick of RAM, because I've seen many solved cases where the RAM was the issue?

And if the ports are really dead, how can I keep the current system by putting this SSD into a new configuration, how much ''similar'' the new config needs to be to function properly? Thanks

Comment: Did you try returning the old disk?

Comment: I haven't. Will try to see will it boot Windows on it. Though this one was working fine for ~3 months, with good temps

Comment: Does it make any beeping sounds?   Beeping sounds on startup usually indicate an error code which can help you in the correct direction.

Comment: Posted an update #2, @davidgo No, there are no beeping sounds on startup. It's a bit ''exotic'' device, not a regular desktop PC. It just starts as soon as you plug the adapter into wall power, lights on a power button turns on, CPU fan starts spinning and nothing else happens.

Comment: F2, f8,f9,f10,f11 are all possibilities for booting to BIOS.

Comment: In manual it says ''Delete'' or F7. The monitor goes into power saving mode, while it works fine with another PC

Comment: Yeah, I have a similar device - newer model CPU, slightly flasher looking case, but similar.  I rebooted it and it does talk about <DEL> and <F7>.  I think that we own the junk we bought...  I fear its a problem on the motherboard.

Comment: I just can't accept that all ports are fried. It doesn't even show the logo, nothing. There was an outage probably during the night, and it was probably set to turn on when the power comes back (didn't know it's a (default) option). Never had this happen in decades. It is a junk indeed, I don't know what to do now. I don't know what MiniPC I can cheaply get to transfer this SSD and hopefully have running system

Comment: And I think it's impossible to buy MOBO replacement for this...