# MiniPC really dead/moving the drive to another system

Tags: memory, ssd, desktop-computer

I posted earlier [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1782963/minipc-started-showing-black-screen-overnight), and after speaking with a tech rep, he thinks it's a hardware issue. I still hope there still may be a fix for this, I've never had such issues, that 0 ports are working. HDMI/DP, USB 2.0/USB 3.0, monitor goes into power saving mode and I can't switch caps lock/num lock lights. The CPU fan is working, there is no PSU (adapter).

Should I try buying a new stick of RAM, because I've seen many solved cases where the RAM was the issue?

And if the ports are really dead, how can I keep the current system by putting this SSD into a new configuration, how much ''similar'' the new config needs to be to function properly?
Thanks

Comment: Please don't open multiple questions on the same post.  Edit your original post instead.

Comment: Edited, thanks @davidgo